# Get multiple subplots in matplotlib from a data table (col_x and col_y) based on col_z information

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have 4 columns in my table including die_id, data, time, and interval. I want to create subplots based on the len(die_id) for nrows and len(interval) for cols.

I tried the following code but it does not work because axes is an numpy.ndarray. How to unravel the index and make it work? Please advise. Thanks.

---

```
nrows = len(df['die_id'].unique())
ncols = len(df['interval'].unique())

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(20,15))

for subplot_number, (die_id, data) in enumerate(df.groupby(['die_id','interval'])):
    axes[subplot_number].plot(data['time_inspect'], data['mean_vc'])
    axes[subplot_number].set_title('DieID: {}'.format(die_id))
    axes[subplot_number].set_ylabel('mean_vc (V)')
    axes[subplot_number].set_xlabel('time_inspect')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access subplots using row and column indices:

```
nrows = len(df['die_id'].unique())
ncols = len(df['interval'].unique())

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(20,15))

for subplot_number, (die_id, data) in enumerate(df.groupby(['die_id','interval'])):
    row = subplot_number // nrows
    col = subplot_number % nrows
    axes[row][col].plot(data['time_inspect'], data['mean_vc'])
    axes[row][col].set_title('DieID: {}'.format(die_id))
    axes[row][col].set_ylabel('mean_vc (V)')
    axes[row][col].set_xlabel('time_inspect')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: It works. Do you mind share how to set same axis for each row? Thanks.

Comment: That's probably a separate question. Have a search on SO, and if you can't find the answer you could make a new question. This might help - https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html